# OpenCV over WSL: select() timeout, usb usb1: Not yet implemented

Tags: linux-kernel, windows-subsystem-for-linux, webcam, v4l2, usbipd

When I try to run OpenCV over WSL using the usbipd_win library and a recompiled kernel (enabled UVC support), I get the error message `[ WARN:0@30.423] global cap_v4l.cpp:1119 tryIoctl VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): select() timeout.`
dmesg:

```
usb usb1: Not yet implemented
usb usb1: Not yet implemented
... repeated "Not yet implemented" and "callbacks suppressed lines"
usb usb1: Not yet implemented
usb usb1: Not yet implemented
usb usb1: Not yet implemented
usb usb1: Not yet implemented
usb usb1: Not yet implemented
vhci_hcd: unlink->seqnum 26060
vhci_hcd: the urb (seqnum 26060) was already given back
vhci_hcd: unlink->seqnum 26065
vhci_hcd: the urb (seqnum 26065) was already given back
uvcvideo 1-1:1.1: Failed to resubmit video URB (-1).
vhci_hcd: unlink->seqnum 26067
vhci_hcd: the urb (seqnum 26067) was already given back
vhci_hcd: unlink->seqnum 26071
vhci_hcd: the urb (seqnum 26071) was already given back
vhci_hcd: unlink->seqnum 26073
vhci_hcd: the urb (seqnum 26073) was already given back
```

uname -a:
`Linux LAPTOP-0KQUO0A2 5.15.83.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2+ #1 SMP ...`

Comment: issue is with `usbipd`. file the bug with the USB/IP project or linux kernel. reproduce with guvcview or VLC or ffmpeg/ffplay. this is not an OpenCV issue. https://linux-usb.vger.kernel.narkive.com/xGgVXYu4/patch-0-3-usbip-move-usbip-out-of-staging

Comment: Yes, but could anyone explain what the error message means?

Comment: it means they didn't "yet" implement something. you can either do that for them (open source), or file an issue for them to fix this.